# How to train tensorflow / machine learning what strings should match?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I have two input names from different sources and they do not match exactly, but I know how to match them by certain clues.

For example,

```
NYCC REMOTE FINANCE 05212020 Fri  05 Jun 2020 03 54 19  0000
```

matches

```
Committee on Finance__2020-05-21T00:00:00
```

I'd like to use machine learning to input 1000's of matching and non-matching strings

Then, after training I'd like to pass two strings and ask if they match.

Here's a link to the training sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rXOj43WYB5hrzOKexRcVU9uj4n4eTJhpxLOZlOQ9s2k/edit?usp=sharing

I tried using Semantic Search with Approximate Nearest Neighbors and Text Embeddings from TF-Hub

see https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1FWMlK8ms_3FOcR8zlAhWval3Zubs_gE-?usp=sharing

But it does not seem to specific enough.  It is only finding nearest neighbors.

I'd like to tell the model what matches look like and then given two new strings, ask if they match.

For example,

```
Committee on Education 05272020 Thu  28 May 2020 15 00 17  0000
```

DOES NOT MATCH

```
Committee on Criminal Justice__2020-03-09T00:00:00
```

Then ask the question: Does

`NYCC Committee on Health w Others 05262020 Wed  27 May 2020 13 52 13  0000`

match

`Committee on Health__2020-05-26T00:00:00`
?

and of course many more new strings.

I could do this in a static program but the input is not under my control and they vary it and I'd like to simply sample the data and re-train the model and have it tell me the matches into the future.

Is there a colab notebook for this?

Thanks.

Comment: My first intuition would be to tokenize the strings.

Comment: Thanks but this must be kind of a common thing where we train on matching examples.  And then expect it to learn what matches in the future. no?  Do you know of a web page that talks about us.  Or a colab example?   Thanks for answering.